# Fixing image responsiveness via pure CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive

I run a Django-based instagram clone where users share photos with others. Photos appear with styling that makes them look like polaroids. Moreover, captions are added within the polaroid styling, not outside it. Here's an example:

[image]

My question is: how do I make the image responsive (in pure CSS)? Currently, it's aspect ratio gets skewed for smaller windows (only width is responsive, height is not). Observe:

[image]

---

Here's how my code looks currently:

```
<style>

.polaroid{
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #9E9E9E; 
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #9E9E9E;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #9E9E9E;
}

.inner_img{
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

.img_caption{
    display: table-caption;
    caption-side: bottom;
    width:100%;
}

</style>

<div class="polaroid">
<img src="{{ tup.1|s3 }}" width="{{ tup.3 }}" height="{{ tup.4 }}" class="inner_img" alt="photo">
<div class="img_caption">{{ tup.5 }}</div>                       
</div>
```

---

Note I: I'd prefer to stick close to well-supported HTML4/CSS2 elements (as listed on caniuse.com) for max compatibility.

Note II: Don't be alarmed by syntax containing `{{ }}`. These are Django template variables that contain useful values for the html tags. E.g. `width="{{ tup.3 }}" height="{{ tup.4 }}"` translates to `width="300" height="224"` for this particular image.

Comment: What you are trying to do is illogic. If it lose width, it must gain height. This is responsive already.

Comment: If you want less height you can make the used font smaller

Comment: @MarcoSalerno: I'd like to keep the aspect ratio of the `<img>` intact. Logical enough?

Comment: just add height: auto; to your img

Comment: @Jiib: Nice and simple. Please add that as answer :-)

Comment: Please remember, w3schools is just a information provider. In any case it is not defining the W3C standards for HTML or CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the aspect ratio of an img, add:

```
img {
   height: auto;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For responsive image.

```
img{
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: auto; /* For center the image */
    margin-right: auto; /* For center the image */
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I hope 'height' attribute given in CSS wouldn't override the inline 'height' since the precedence during page render.

Comment: `height` and `width` `attribute` will over wright the external `CSS`. This isn't good method to make `image` responsive. So `height` and `width` attribute will be remove from the `img` `tag`.

Comment: CSS precedence to render would be like 
1. External CSS 2. Internal CSS 3. Inline CSS. 

In this case, your External CSS will apply first then the page will apply any other Internal CSS lines and then finally it will apply the inline CSS style. In this case, your CSS line will be overrided by the inline style 'height'.

Comment: It is always better to control CSS style from external stylesheet without touching the HTML file.

Comment: Rahul, how is using `margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;` superior to using `margin: 0 auto; margin-bottom: 20px;`?

Comment: Your writing `css` okay. But use separate  `margin property` it will not conflict the code. Better if you use responsive image `class` are globally. Like `.img-fluid` or `.img-responsive` `class`. Property will be `.img-fluid{display: block;height: auto;max-width: 100%;}`. Now you can set the image `margin` using `local class` like `.polaroid img{margin-bottom: 20px;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;}` or `.polaroid img{margin: 0 auto 20px;}`

Answer (score 1):

@Hassan Baig,

You should avoid to mention both 'width' and 'height' attributes otherwise the image will get stretch like this.

For this case, you should remove the 'height' property from the image in HTML or you can add 'height: auto !important' in CSS to override the inline style.

'!important' will override the existing height value and it will allow the image to set height auto based on the width.

Hope it would be helpful!.

Comment: Interesting, why should I not mention `height`? Care to explain further? I thought this helps with DOM processing and rendering

Comment: According to w3schools: Always specify both the `height` and `width` attributes for images. If `height` and `width` are set, the space required for the image is reserved when the page is loaded.

Comment: yes. I accept. But it is not mandatory to do. I am not saying, you shouldn't use 'height' attribute. You can set it by 'auto !important'. It should override any 'height' attribute value set as inline style.

Comment: In any case, you bring up another point that I've been concerned about. Although I'm hardcording height and width within the `img` tag, I notice that before the image has loaded, my browser reserves enough space for the height of the image, but it reserves no space at all for the width. Any ideas what could be going on?

Answer (score 0):

You have hardcoded height in your IMG tag (html), thats making a problem.
Just remove the height parameter from IMG tag and the image will auto adjust.

Comment: Okay, but in that case, I've hardcoded width in the `img` tag too, no? Moreover, I put those values in because it helps with rendering. According to w3schools: Always specify both the `height` and `width` attributes for images. If `height` and `width` are set, the space required for the image is reserved when the page is loaded.

Comment: @HassanBaig `height` and `width` `attribute` like as `fixed height and width`. For responsive image you can't set `height and width attribute` in `img tag`.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove te inline height and width of the image and set the image width and height in your CSS to:

```
img {
   height: auto;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change div's max-width to see it responsive

```css
div {
  display: table;
  max-width: 100px;
}

img {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

label {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e1/Bauhaus.JPG"/><label>Oh my god this place is so beautiful please buy pizza for me</label></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Hope it works